# How do I convert vector line equation to a scalar equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have a line $Ax+By+C=0$

We know the perpendicular vector to the line is $ A \vec{i} + B \vec{j}$

The equation of perpendicular line should be;
$$ s= (xo,yo) + t ( A,B)$$

where t is the parameter and $(xo,yo)$ is some point on this perpendicular line.

Is it possible to invert the sequence of steps to find the original line back from this?

Comment: Once you have the parametric equation, you can substitute a nonzero value for $t$ to get a point $(x_1,y_1)$ on the line. Then you'll have two distinct points $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$, both on the line. You should be able to finish.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is unclear if you are after the equation of the line by $P_0$, or the perpendicular by $P_0$ or whatnot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Write your equation as a system of equations
$$x=x_0+tA$$
$$y=y_0+tB$$
and eliminate $t$

Comment: exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Very simple: if the cartesian equation of the line is 
$$Ax+By+C=0\qquad(C\text{ to be determined})$$
and if the line passes through the point $(x_0,y_0)$, this equation can be rewritten as
$$Ax+By=Ax_0+By_0.$$

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Why not? The O.P. asks how to convert from a vector to a cartesian equation. Further, I think it's a good mnemonic.

Comment: Mh, after all the question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The line $$Ax+By+C=0$$ certainly passes through

$$(x_0,y_0)=\left(-\dfrac{AC}{A^2+B^2},-\dfrac{BC}{A^2+B^2}\right).$$

The normal direction is $$\propto(A,B)$$ and the direction itself is orthogonal,

$$\propto(B,-A).$$

Hence the parametric equations

$$\begin{cases}x=x_0+Bt,\\y=y_0-At.\end{cases}$$

---

Now the *orthogonal* line through the same point has the direction $\propto(A,B)$, hence

$$\begin{cases}x=x_0+At,\\y=y_0+Bt,\end{cases}$$

corresponding (by elimination of $t$) to the implicit equation

$$B(x-x_0)-A(y-y_0)=0$$

or

$$Bx+(-A)y+(Ay_0-Bx_0)=0.$$

---

Note that with our particular choice of the point $(x_0,y_0)$, the latter reduces to

$$Bx=Ay,$$ a line by the origin. But the equations work for other points.

---

If you any *any* line perpendicular to

$$Ax+By+C=0,$$ it suffices to consider

$$Bx-Ay+D=0$$ where $D$ is arbitrary. The common point is

$$\left(-\frac{BD+AC}{A^2+B^2},-\frac{BC-AD}{A^2+B^2}\right).$$